# ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'- only Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I've just installed matplotlib through pip, everything works perfectly when using python with terminal. But when I'm trying to do the same in Pycharm Community Edition there's a problem. It's strange to me that it works but not with Pycharm. Didn't find any fix that fits my problem. I'm attaching img so it'll be clear what's the problem.

Terminal:
[image: Terminal]

PyCharm:
[image: Pycharm]

Comment: Are you using same version of python in both cases? From your images it's not clear whether python3 and python3.6 are pointing to same version. Make sure the python path is set properly in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

You are using python 3.5 on the terminal and Python 3.6 on PyCharm. You need to install matplotlib on the right distribution or use Python3.5 in Pycharm. Change it in: `File > Settings > Projet Interpreter`

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed the interpreter and it works (3.5 version had almost no libraries added- I remember installing it but I had to add it manually). But the strange thing is- when I try to install matplotlib the same way I got an error. When I do what Pycharm wants me to do it says that matplotlib is already installed...

[Pycharm Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1lcr.png)

[Already there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrycS.png)